# How to determine if post has widget content?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I've got a registered sidebar called "my-header" that affects the absolute positioning of elements below it in the markup.

So I need to execute a query in header.php to determine if the sidebar is present for the current post, and write out a class identifier to my theme's body tag. I'll use this css class to adjust absolute positioning of elements accordingly.

Is there a method that can be called, separately from the method that's used to display the sidebar, to determine if the post has widget content for the "my-sidebar" widget? For example, one that just returns true/false?

After looking through widgets.php, I tried using is_active_sidebar('my-header') but it returns true for all pages. I need a function that accepts the post as an argument. Otherwise, if none exists, I suppose I'll create my own function.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Justin Tadlock's My Snippets plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-snippets/

Comment: @Manzabar: looks nifty. I've had this on my list to add to my theme for some time. I appreciate the reference.

Comment: Could you please explain this part - _if the post has widget content for the "my-sidebar" widget_ . Posts and widgets are completely different things, they do not intersect, unless you use some custom context-aware widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$bodyclass = "";
// are we on a 'single' page? e.g. a post or page or some other custom post type?
if(is_single()){
    // is this a post of type 'page'? or is it a blogpost?
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'page'){
        // good now to check if we have a sidebar with active content
        if( is_active_sidebar('my-header')){
            $bodyclass="wehavesidebarcontentyay";
        }
    }
}

?>
<body <?php body_class($bodyclass); ?>>
```

Though I'm sure if you have body_class on your body tag then you already have the needed css classes and selectors to do this without the PHP code.